# RestAssured - how to check id in <a id="some number"></a>?

Tags: java, xml, rest, junit, rest-assured

I am testing a web service, which returns an xml like in the example below

```
<test xmlns="some url">
   <a id="482b6f66-0543-49b2-9a22-d70dc1a87032" href="some url">some text</a>
</test>
```

I looked through RestAssured documentation but I could not find how to check individual xml properties. I want to test "id" property, returned in the response, but my test fails, telling me that actual vs expected is empty, though I can clearly see that the tag is there and id value is present, if I output xml response as a String.

Here's my test:

```
expect().body("test.a.id", equalTo(expectedId)).when().post(myRequest);
```

Comment: don't think it's relevant in this case

Answer (score 3):

You were missing a `@`
should be :

```
expect().body("test.a.@id", equalTo(expectedId)).when().post(myRequest);
```

Comment: You. literally. Save. My. Life 8-)

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since your response is XML you can use XPath:

```
expect().body(hasXPath("/test/a/@id"), equalTo(expectedId)).when().post(myRequest);
```

`@` is the way you should address attributes in xpath. Note that this might also help you with a solution using XMLPath. (see the examples [here](http://rest-assured.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.9.0/apidocs/index.html))

Perhaps your usage of namespaces might give some troubles though, you can enable that using:

```
given().
    config(newConfig().xmlConfig(xmlConfig().with().namespaceAware(true))).
expect().
    body(hasXPath("/yourns:test/yourns:a/@id"), equalTo(expectedId)).when().post(myRequest);
```

see also: http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#XPath

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising, but now I am getting this error:

**org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "HR" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</HR>".
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)**

Comment: That's a bit of a shame, because it means that your XML is not valid XML (html rarely is..) In al probability you might not be able to use the hasXPath option nor the XMLPath option. (unless ofcourse you can guarentee valid XML outputs from the server). Maybe you can still adress attributes with `@` but I didn't find anything about that for html output.

Comment: Good news, using @ solved it for me! Will post a solution in a bit. Thanks a lot for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be a bit ugly, but I could not find any relevant examples of this usage, so it's all a guess work. Maybe there's a better way, but here's what I came up with:

Here's the code to find and print my id:

```
String xml = get(myRequest).asString();
XmlPath xmlPath = new XmlPath(xml).setRoot("test");
String id = xmlPath.get("a.@id");
Assert.assertTrue(id.equals(expectedId));
```

Comment: Above helped me to parse through html response easily by setting root as form. Used restassured to get response.

XmlPath xmlPathForWSResult = new XmlPath(response.body().toString()).setRoot("form");
        String Req9WAResult = xmlPathForWSResult.get("form.input[1].@value");
        System.out.println("Retrieved REQ9WAResult Value >> " + Req9WAResult);

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with xml:

```
<example id="12345">
    <someStuff></someStuff>
</example>
```

I could verify the attribute using:

```
given().
when().
    post("/example/get/").
then().
    body(
        "example.@id", equalTo("12345")
    );
```